# How to recreate pmouseY & pmouseX (processing.JS variables) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent, processing.js

How can you create the `pmouseY` and `pmouseX` variables that are inbuilt-variables in the processing.JS javascript library.

`pmouseX` represents the previous x-coordinate of the mouse 
`pmouseY` represents the previous y-coordinate of the mouse

Whilst the normal mouseX/Y (which correspond to the javascript event.clientY/X variables) are the current position of the mouse. 
Here is a pastebin of what I tried to do: 
http://pastebin.com/XSu3XHAJ 
Where I just tried making the `pmouseX/Y` by decreasing the current X/Y position of the mouse by one.
This is an attempt at a javascript recreation of this khanacademy "project": 
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/pmousex-pmousey-processingjs/5082026180870144

Spoiler alert: it didn't at all come close to the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler, store the mouse position. That way, on the next frame, that variable is the mouse position from the previous frame.

```
var pmX, pmY;

function createLines(event) {

    var mX = event.clientX;
    var mY = event.clientY;

    if (pmX && pmY) {
        board.beginPath();
        board.moveTo(pmX, pmY);
        board.lineTo(mX, mY);
        board.stroke();
    }

    pmX = mX;
    pmY = mY;

}
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle or a quick example? Feel free to use my code in the linked pastebin.

Comment: @Axeowny: see edit. Added the essential parts, you can add the rest (line color, canvas, context).

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you answer a question? What is the if (pmX && pmY) doing? I understand that it means if pmX and pmY === true then do this but there isn't anything that changes or defines a boolean value for the pmX/Y. Does it mean if pmX and pmY have a value then do this?

Comment: @Axeowny: yes, it means if both pmX and pmY have a value. The first time this function is run, pmX and pmY are unset, because there is no previous position (it's the first). That expression prevents a line from being drawn in that case.

Comment: How does the computer know if you mean "if this has a value" rather than "if this is true"?